# How can I make this JSON.stringify work properly

Tags: javascript, json

I have a small issue to make my arrays into the json I want to. I have made this code:

```js
var arrData = [{label:Test,value:199.12}, {label:Test2,value:1024}]     
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
  data.push(JSON.stringify({
    label: arrData[i][2],
    value: arrData[i][3]
  }).replace(/\"/g, "").replace("\\r", ""))
}
```

It also does the job properly. But I do want it to be in this format:

> { label: 'Food', value: 90 },

I want to have the ' ' on the label data and I want to remove the double "" punctuation mark outside the json. Since my current json looks like this:

```
"{label:Test,value:199.12}", "{label:Test2,value:1024}",
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify` *does* work properly. What you seem to want is to produce invalid JSON.

Comment: *"Since my current json looks like this"* The code in the question definitely **won't** produce that "JSON" (which isn't JSON).

Comment: Please update the snippet I made with relevant data

Comment: @Ayrton it should actually be `{"label":"Test","value":199.12}`. Anything else is not valid.

Comment: JSON is not actually the same as a Javascript object - it's somewhat simplified. You can only use double quotes on labels (you are not allowed to omit them) and as Ayton pointed out, you can only use double quotes to signify string literals. You need to either write the program that receives this structure to accept proper JSON, or write your own stringify function that follows your own rules if you really want to make up your own data format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ label: 'Food', value: 90 }` isn't valid JSON so you cannot create it using `JSON.stringify`.

It isn't any standard serialisation format (although it is a valid JavaScript literal) so if you want to serialise data to it, you'll need to write a custom serialiser.

You could loop over the properties of the object and append them, the associated values, and whatever quotes and commas your format demands, to a string.